# Exception catching didn't work on my method ?

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

I'm using eclipse IDE and following picture is a method from SQLiteOpenHelper class. The exception occurs at line number 417. After executing that line in debugging mode and then the log show as shown in picture. But the debugging line never entered into line number 419 where I put a breakpoint. Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: Could you post logcat. I want to see what the exception is?

Comment: It's SQLiteConstraintException. I tried to catch it first but didn't work. That's why I changed it to Exception. Still didn't work.

Comment: Something similar happened to me in Android Studio. Had to debug with my mate's device to try some things, and when the execution enters a try catch block, the exception was not captured. Are you debugging with a "M" device?

Comment: No., I'm using GenyMotion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to change the method name from `insert` to `insertOrThrow` and add a `try catch block`.See if this work.You can check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) reference.